# Invalid hook call react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hi I am a new React user and I am trying to add the following component to an app I'm developing:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';

function InAppCamera() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera style={styles.camera} type={type}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(type === CameraType.back ? CameraType.front : CameraType.back);
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.text}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 20,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.1,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
  },
});

export default InAppCamera;
```

I am trying to reference this component in another .js file as seen below:

```
<FAB style={styles.fab} small icon="camera" onPress={InAppCamera} />
```

I get an error for an invalid hook call. Any suggestions would be great thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post the full error you get?

Comment: What are you trying to do onPress of FAB?

Comment: You're trying to pass a react component to the `onPress` method. React is likely upset that the number of calls to the hooks changes across renders without a proper unmount because that's not how you're supposed to render React components. You're passing the wrong value to the `onPress` prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//You can get some idea from the given sample.

const [showCamera, setCamera] = useState(false);


return <View>

    /*Other Code If any */

    <FAB style={styles.fab} small icon="camera" onPress={() => setCamera(!showCamera)} />

    {showCamera ? <InAppCamera /> : null}

    /*Other Code If any */

</View>
```